# Angular 7: Want to display html page without creating extra component

Tags: angular, typescript

In my application if a user is not verified but exists ...So I wanted to show him an html page .. What should I do ?? I saw on internet that 2 division and switch from that .. But I don't want to that..

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but if you are asking how to just show a an HTML page based on some logic, the answer is that you can't.

Angular is a component-based framework. To display content, you must use a component.
HTML is used to provide the component's visual representation, but the HTML cannot stand on it's own without the component.

Answer (score 0):

1. Be careful with using the angularjs vs Angular tags as they are different. Read more [here](https://www.educba.com/angular-js-vs-angular/)
2. You probably want a template directive. Perhaps *ngIf which only renders the content if the if statement is true. [Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtT01ZCHRjk) to explain more.